# Problem with DynamoDBMapper load functionality

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

Update and delete functionalities are working fine but for reading(and query) I am getting this as output instead of content of item. I am using Android Studio.

```
09-20 02:03:37.086 32346-32373/com.simran.awstestapp I/System.out: News: 
com.amazonaws.models.nosql.NotesDO@5adba4

09-20 02:03:37.087 32346-32373/com.simran.awstestapp D/News Item:: 
com.amazonaws.models.nosql.NotesDO@5adba4
```

This is my code:

```
public void readNews() {

    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            NotesDO newsItem = dynamoDBMapper.load(
                    NotesDO.class,
                    "myuser",
                    "myid");

            // Item read
             System.out.println("News: " + newsItem);
             Log.d("News Item:", newsItem.toString());
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Please help me. I have been stuck on this for last two days.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try printing the desired content attribute of "newsItem", the NotesDO object instead of displaying the object itself. If that doesn't give you the desired output, can you please provide the details of NotesDO class?

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I realized that load functionality was not what I needed. I had to use query because I have alot of items in DynamoD Table.